# Subversion Edge on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversion-edge

How can I configure subversion edge on eclipse. I have no experience with that. If someone could tell me the steps I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it. Just installed CollabNet desktop for eclipse. That easy!